# Have setMnemonic underline a character other than the first occurrence

Tags: java, swing

In a re-implementation of an existing program, I would like to keep the message text that users are familiar with. One of the enhancements I'd like to add is a good keyboard-only interface including mnemonics. But using the intuitive mnemonic character with the existing text gives some ugly results. For example:

```
    useUpperCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Use UPPERCASE letters");
    useUpperCheckBox.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_U);
```

underlines the "U" in "Use" rather than the "U" in "UPPERCASE". Since the user's eye is naturally drawn to "UPPERCASE" looking for a mnemonic, the default location of the decoration is a bit unintuitive.

Yes, I've read the docs and the tutorials that say that the first instance of the mnemonic character is underlined, but that isn't what I want. It comes up often enough that I can't believe I'm the only one frustrated by this. Surely someone smarter than me has figured out how to place the decoration somewhere different than the default location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the source, Luke. Looking at the source code of `setMnemonic()` led me quickly to [`AbstractButton.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(int)):

> Provides a hint to the look and feel
>   as to which character in the text
>   should be decorated to represent the
>   mnemonic.

Comment: +1 for teaching how to find the answer rather just giving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is: [setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(int index)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setDisplayedMnemonicIndex%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

I realise this isn't the situation here, but it is related:

If you are using AbstractAction, try `putValue(DISPLAYED_MNEMONIC_INDEX_KEY, index);`.